# Eliminar sólo el registro de una tabla join caso categorías de productos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, table

Buen día compañeros.
Mis modelos y vistas de ROR son los siguientes:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    
    has_many :category_producto, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :producto, through: :category_producto

    validates :nombre, presence:true
    
    after_update :save_productos

    # Custom setter
    def productos=(value)
        @productos = value
            
    end

    def save_productos
        # raise @productos.to_yaml

        @productos.each do |producto_id|
             CategoryProducto.create(category_id: self.id, producto_id: producto_id)
        end
    end
end
```

```
class CategoryProducto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  
  belongs_to :producto
  
end
```

```
class Producto < ApplicationRecord
    
    has_many :category_producto, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :category, through: :category_producto

    validates :codigo, presence: true
    validates :nombre, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}

    after_create :save_categories
    after_update :save_categories

    # Custom setter
    def categories=(value)
        @categories = value     
    end

    def save_categories
        # raise @categories.to_yaml

        @categories.each do |category_id|
             CategoryProducto.create(category_id: category_id, producto_id: self.id)
        end
    end

end
```

La vista del edit: con esto puedo agregar los categorías que pertenece el producto

```
<%= select_tag "categories[]", options_for_select(@categories.collect{|x| [x.nombre,x.id]}), {:class => "form-control", include_blank: true} %>
```

La Vista del show:

```
<tbody> 
          <% @category.producto.each do |prod| %>
            <tr>

              <td><%= link_to prod.nombre, prod %></td>
              
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" size="8"><%= link_to 'Quitar', @category.producto.delete(prod), style: 'color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "¿Está seguro de quitar #{prod.nombre} de esta categoría?"} %></button>
                
              </td>
              
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

Con esto consigo que los productos tenga muchas categorías y las categorías tengan muchos productos, puedo agregar con un select. El problema está en quitar un producto de una categoría (no eliminar el producto) o también el quitar una categoría del producto (no eliminar la categoría).
Cuando uso eto @category.producto.delete(prod) en un each esto lo que hace es eliminar todos los productos de esa categoría. M epodrían ayudar de que forma puedo quitar los porductos de una categoría y viceversa por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primera cosa, en:

```
<%= link_to 'Quitar', @category.producto.delete(prod), style: 'color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "¿Está seguro de quitar #{prod.nombre} de esta categoría?"} %>
```

no deberías llamar a `@category.producto.delete(prod)`, porque efectivamente lo que estás haciendo ahí es llamando a ese comando en cada iteración de `@category.producto.each`. De hecho el borrar debe hacerse a nivel de controlador, no de vista.
Lo segundo, iterando como:

```
<% @category.producto.each do |prod| %>
```

es incorrecto, debería ser sobre `@category.category_producto`, así al momento de borrar, borras la relación que existe entre category y producto, no el producto en si mismo. Deberías dejar algo como:

```
      <% @category.category_producto.each do |cat_prod| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to cat_prod.producto.nombre, cat_prod.producto %></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" size="8">
              <%= link_to 'Quitar', ruta_para_borrar_path(cat_prod.id), style: 'color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "¿Está seguro de quitar #{cat_prod.producto.nombre} de esta categoría?"} %>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

Luego, en el controlador que tengas (o si quieres crear un `scaffold` específico para `category_productos`, que creo es lo mejor), ahí recibes el id de la relación y en tu action de `destroy` llamas a:

```
  CategoryProducto.destroy(params[:id])
```

Comment: Gracias. Lo hice tal cual y funciona perfectamente. Creé la ruta resources :category_productos, only: [:destroy] y el controlador con el método destroy, antes del método destroy agregué @cat_prod = CategoryProducto.find(params[:id]) para luego del destroy hacer un redirect con redirect_to edit_category_path(@cat_prod.category_id), :notice => "Producto quitado correctamente" o podría hacerlo con ajax, lo bueno es que está funcionando como yo quería. Otra vez Gracias.